# Change Console Color by Providing a string

Tags: c#, colors, console-application

I want to change my Console BackgroundColor based on the color name as a string, like "Red" or "Blue".

This is a rough example:

```
public void ChangeBackGroundColor(string ColorName)
{
    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.ColorName;
    Console.Clear();
}
```

It should change the BackgroundColor of the Console.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the string `ColorName` to the appropriate enum value:

```
Console.BackgroundColor = (ConsoleColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(ConsoleColor), ColorName, true);
Console.Clear();
```

Comment: this will throw exception if `ColorName` is not represented in `ConsoleColor`

Comment: @currarpickt - yes, so there will need to be some error handling, but that's outside the scope of the example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string into `ConsoleColor` enum type. `Enum.Parse` will throw exception if `ColorName` is not represented in `ConsoleColor`. Therefore, you could use `TryParse` to prevent the exception and handle it separately.

```
public void ChangeBackGroundColor(string ColorName)
 {
     ConsoleColor consoleColor;

     if (Enum.TryParse(ColorName, out consoleColor))
     {
         // We now have an enum type.
         Console.BackgroundColor = consoleColor;
         Console.Clear();
     }

     //do whatever you want if it's invalid ColorName    
     Console.WriteLine("invalid color");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple variation, using [Enum.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Enum.TryParse%60%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) to skip non existing colors:

```
private static void ChangeBackGroundColor(string ColorName)
{
    if (Enum.TryParse(ColorName, out ConsoleColor Color))
        Console.BackgroundColor = Color;
    Console.Clear();
}
```